Setup Application Base requirements with a single command in Laravel
I am trying to create a starter application using Laravel that can used with any other project.
This would include, multiple authentications using guards, routes, controllers, validations, single page frontends etc.
I would like to get all of this up and running by using a single command.
So if I want to begin working on a new project I would do
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^XX.0 my-new-app

composer require my-custom-package

php artisan abracadabra

By doing this, I would like the routes to be copied to the routes file, controllers, models, views, migrations, seeds, traits copied to the respective directories, add custom middleware to $routeMiddleware, guards to be added, observers to be added, etc etc etc.
I am aware I can just create a starter template but when laravel upgrades to the next major release, I want to use this starter kit. (My current problem)
In addition, when there is some feature I want to include across all projects, I can just
composer update my-custom-package
I am not sure how to begin achieving this.
Any ideas are welcome.

Nonono. Make fresh project, add everything you need in starter complect and push in repo. Than  composer create-project your_repo/laravel-skeleton

I currently use this approach but when I want to start with the next major version of Laravel, I have to do everything again. It took me about 4 months to setup the starter kit so that I can use it for projects.
I am trying to avoid the re-work annually as Laravel upgrades once a year.

The first step in this whole process is to create a custom package, but before you learn how to create a package you need to have a deep understanding of Laravel core concepts such as service providers and service containers.
Luckily, there are several resources that can get you started such as the package development section of Laravel documentation, and the website https://www.laravelpackage.com/ which has an excellent tutorial that covers these steps in detail.
After that, you will need to create your package. Spatie has a package skeleton project with a convenient installer that can scaffold an entire package for you as a starting point with many features.
The last step would be to publish your package to https://packagist.org to make it available as a composer package.
